# Change name of route path in browser only

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to write two different routes to two pages like

```
 { path: 'abc', component: abcComponent},
 { path: 'abc2', component: abcComponent2},
```

as browser show me path:

http://localhost:4200/abc2 on accessing second route path.

Can I somehow have the same name for two components ie I want the browser to display only

http://localhost:4200/abc even if calling route path: 'abc2';

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need this, but if you want to do that just paste this line of code in constructor of abcComponent2 constructor:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('abc', { skipLocationChange: true });
```

or you can also change router without changing location via html like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="..." skipLocationChange>click me</a>
```

Comment: Hi Shashank, Thanks for your answer but it is based on the data received from the previous page and I need to route to two successful pages with different content but I want the browser should show the same name as successful instead of successful-1 and successful-2.

Comment: i want to help but i think i still didn't get you what you want. as per i know you want to redirect to component_A from Component_B if somemone open component_B without changing path in browser.